# How to log from within an AWS ElasticBeanStalk application to an accessible log? [IIS/.NET]

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use Amazon ElasticBeanStalk to host my .Net application, but it seems that I cannot access or set up my application log file properly.

I am currently using Nlog to log from within my Application but I do not know how to access that log-file.

I am new to AWS ElasticBeanStalk, so I hope somebody could help me with application logging.

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation on log files in Elastic Beanstalk: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: I did, but to be honest, no examples regarding IIS/.Net-development. But thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1. Access the log by RDP: You open an RDP terminal and then you download or view the file remotely
2. Use a log server: We are using graylog on a separate instance and log (with log4net though) to it. This leverages our use of the log data considerably, as we can also generate statistics, dashboards and common warnings if something is really wrong.
3. Using the CloudWatch logging facilities: We had problems setting this up; lines were truncated, you need to configure it on the instance and then in the .ebextensions file, etc.

We started with 1, and then tried 3. But finally we moved to 2, because it really gives us many advantages. Many log servers make use of a locally (on the EB instance) installed service; this is something that you'll need to properly configure when deploying the application each time, not always that easy to do. With the current setup with graylog, it's just a configuration item in the Web.config or App.Config. And, at least for log4net, it's very easy to use and we did not have to change one line of code when moving from 1 to 3. Setting up a graylog server is quite easy and AMIs exist for it.

Comment: Hi Marco

Thanks for your answer, I will try to play arround with option 3 and maybe go to a option 2. But it would be lovely to get the Amazon out of the box Logging-support working.

Comment: Good luck with it. If you find an easy way to properly configure it, can you share your results? However, I have just found this on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html => You cannot configure CloudWatch Logs integration with Elastic Beanstalk applications created in .NET containers. Not exactly sure what that means, though. I dimly remember that I saw an example somewhere once.

Comment: I will definitely share if I am able to do it, who knows I will write a blog post somewhere about it describing how to set it up. So fingers crossed.

Comment: And if you can, look also at option 2; I think in an afternoon you can completely set it up end to end. I use the dashboard every day, it greatly leverages the value of our logs (e.g. using internal timings as log message that are averaged on the log server and can also yield alerts, etc.). Looking forward to hear from your experiences.

Answer (score 5):

When I contacted AWS support asking how best to log stuff from within an ASP.NET Core application on Elastic Beanstalk, I received a reply noting that it's impossible to integrate a Windows-based Elastic Beanstalk application's logging with the actual Elastic Beanstalk logs and advising me to use CloudWatch logging instead:

> Hello,
>
> The beanstalk logs uses it's own logic to collect the logs. In the
>   linux verison of it it is possible to simply add the file to the path
>   of the logging, but in windows the logs are collected individually
>   since they use a different type of logging driver to collect the logs,
>   therefore it is not possible to simply add files to a path and see
>   them show up in the beanstalk logging.
>
> what you can do instead of using the built in beanstalk logging is use
>   cloudformation *[sic]* logs instead.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html
>
> with this you should be able to set up a logger that will allow you to
>   send logs directly to amazon cloudwatch logs.
>
> Best regards,
>
> elijah f. Amazon Web Services

The docs linked above were, honestly, not especially helpful to me. However, there are various code examples of logging to CloudWatch at https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet that may well prove more useful than the documentation is. In particular, I found the example using the default ASP.NET Core logging framework helpful, and have since documented in detail how to get ASP.NET Core's `ILogger` to log to CloudWatch at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146001/1709587.

Comment: According to this announcement https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-amazon-cloudwatch-log-streaming-for-windows-platforms/ it should be possible to stream logs now.  Unfortunately I don't see much documentation about how.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Ugh, yes, those docs are shit. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html is unclear on whether the *Setting Up CloudWatch Logs Integration with Configuration Files* is actually necessary for anything to work or whether the log files listed in the table above will be streamed to CloudWatch by default once *Log streaming* is ticked in the EB console; if it *is* necessary to do the config step, that's problematic, because the list of environment-specific config files doesn't include anything for an IIS environment.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Possibly my answer is now obsolete and the approach you've linked to is superior, but I can't tell just by looking, and since I no longer work with a .NET stack I don't fancy burning the hours that are probably needed to figure it all out. But thanks for the link nonetheless; hopefully somebody will try out the new documented solution and either post their own answer describing it or offer up a comment explaining why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah your concerns are spot on; same things I was trying to figure out.  I'm doing a proof of concept of moving to AWS (might consider Azure as well) so if I get further in figuring this out I'll add info to this question.